# seperate equations for iterating over a set and its subset

Tags: pyomo

I am new to Pyomo. I am trying to run two separate equations for iterating over a set and its subset which doesn't give the outcome as expected:

```
model.E = Set(initialize = [0, 1, 2, 3])
model.E_n = Set(model.E, initialize = {0:[1,2,3,4,5], 1:[6,7,8,9,10], 2:[11,12,13,14,15], 3:[16,17,18,19,20]})
model.int_rate = 0.05

def R_discount_inv_init(model, i):
    return sum(1 / (1 + model.int_rate)**(i - 1) for i in model.E)
model.cum_disc_inv_cost = Param(model.E, initialize = R_discount_inv_init)

def R_discount_op_init(model, i):
    for index in model.E_n:
        return sum(1 / (1 + model.int_rate)**(i - 1) for i in model.E_n[index])
model.cum_disc_op_cost = Param(model.E, initialize = R_discount_op_init)
```

I want the first expression to iterate over the set in model.E (Number of Epochs) and the second expression will iterate over its subset, model.E_n (Time period within the Epoch = 5years).

Please is there a better way to code this that will yield desired outcome?

Thank you

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to end up with? Do you expect both of the Params to be indexed by `model.E` or do you expect them to be singleton Params equal to the sums you mentioned?

Comment: Hi Bethany, Yes both Params are indexed by Model.E. but function 1 iterates over the set while function 2 iterates over the subset. The goal is to end up with new lists from each operation.

Comment: Ok, and what do you want those lists to look like? Could you be more explicit in the question by showing the exact expression you would like to initialize `model.cum_disc_inv_cost[0]`, model.cum_disc_inv_cost[1]`, `model.cum_disc_op_cost[0]`, and `model.cum_disc_op_cost[1]`? Do you want to sum over the entire set and subset for every index in `model.E` or do you only want the sum for indices less then i? Write out the expressions you're after and expand the sums.